# Set default layout to a category

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I’m currently working on an Shopware Project and I need to change the default product listing layout.
The problem is that I need to assign this layout to every (new) category.
Is it currently possible to change the default category layout to my custom layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be possible currently,
see [NEXT-16464 in the issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-16464).

In that issue an epic (https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-19261) which was updated today (11 Jul 2022) and is "in progress".